# Cordova App - Open PDF from Expansion File and convert to Base64 String

Tags: android, cordova, pdf

I have a cordova app up and running where I have an expansion file that is hosting a lot of pdf documents. I want to be able to open a pdf file from that expansion file and convert the entire file into a base 64 string in order to print that pdf from my app. I am trying to use this cordova plugin: https://github.com/sarahgoldman/cordova-print-pdf-plugin which is great, but there is no explanation on how to actually create the base 64 string.

I have attempted to use

```
var files = new File([""], "filename.pdf",{type:'application/pdf'});
  console.log(files);
  if (files.length > 0) {
    getBase64(files[0]);
  }
});

function getBase64(file) {
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.readAsDataURL(file);
   reader.onload = function () {
   console.log(reader.result);
   };
  reader.onerror = function (error) {
  console.log('Error: ', error);
  };
```

}

where the filename.pdf is stored in my expansion file but I don't get a proper response from the code.

any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You're really asking two questions in one.

**Expansion Files in Cordova**

To get at the content of your expansion file, I suggest this cordova plugin:
https://github.com/agamemnus/cordova-plugin-xapkreader/tree/cordova-6.5.0
it facilitates accessing files inside of the expansion file so you can do something like this:

`<img src="content://com.test.expansion/myfile.png">`

Key is to follow the installation instructions to the point because this plugin requires more work than most of the other ones I've installed.

**Base64 Encoding in Javascript**

look at the *btoa()* and *atob()* functions. They convert text to and from base64 encoding.
Feed your PDF content to the function and hand that over to the pdf plugin.